# Array sort by Ascending in for loop

Tags: java

I got trouble when i try to sort array in for loop.

I give you my code follow:

```
public class Lottery {

    public Lottery() {
        java.util.Random iRandom = new java.util.Random();
        int num[] = new int[6];
        java.util.Arrays.sort(num);

        for(int i =0 ; i < num.length; i++) {
            java.util.Arrays.sort(num);
            num[i] = iRandom.nextInt(49)+1;
            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lottery lott = new Lottery();
    }
}
```

In my above code, i can print random number for using "For Loop" but i try to sort it by ascending but it doesnt work.....

The way i do is right?

Could everybody can help me?

Thank you!

Best Regards!

Comment: you should probably generate all of the random numbers you want then call Arrays.sort(...)

Comment: You also need to check for duplicate random numbers.  A lottery usually has unique random numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sorting the array as you go through it and inserting data into the array.

What you should be doing is:

```
public Lottery() {
    java.util.Random iRandom = new java.util.Random();
    int num[] = new int[6];
    //java.util.Arrays.sort(num);

    for(int i =0 ; i < num.length; i++) {
        num[i] = iRandom.nextInt(49)+1;
    }

    java.util.Arrays.sort(num);

    for(int i : num) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Put the `Arrays.sort(num)` call **AFTER** you're finished generating the random numbers.

```
public Lottery(){
    java.util.Random iRandom = new java.util.Random();
    int num[] = new int[6];

    for(int i =0 ; i < num.length; i++)
        num[i] = iRandom.nextInt(49)+1;

    Arrays.sort(num);
}
```

Comment: First of all Thank you so much
I try to do follow u but when i print it , it show result such as:
> 0 0 0 13 14 15
but i need range from 1-49
i dont know what problem occur
Thank you !!

Comment: How are you printing it? There's no way to get `num[i]==0` since `iRandom.nextInt(49)+1` will always return an int between 1 and 49

Comment: It's mean can not to print from 1-49? when num[i]=0?

Comment: Try printing the array using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));`.

Answer (score 3):

You're changing the array after you sort it, which breaks the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to sort in acceding order is:

```
 java.util.Arrays.sort(array);
```

edit: Also as said in the comments: Get the random numbers you want. Then sort in revese. (to much sorting can make the program slow)

Comment: he's asking about sorting in ascending order, wouldn't reverse order sort in descending?